# Blade: escaping text and allowing new lines

Tags: php, laravel, escaping, laravel-blade

I have a user-input text displayed on one of the pages. I want to allow new lines, though. How do I display the text, so it is **escaped** AND **allows new lines**?

I used `nl2br()` and Blade's tripple brackets `{{{$text}}}`, however, obviously, the tripple brackets escape `<br/>` tags as well.

Is there a way to combine escaping and HTML's new lines using Blade?

Thanks.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can do the escaping first, using `e()` and then apply `nl2br()`:

```
{{ nl2br(e($text)) }}
```

`e()` is the function Blade uses when compiling triple brackets

Comment: For Laravel 5, use this:

```{!! nl2br(e($text)) !!}```

Comment: @MohitMamoria, what exactly does that do? What is wrong with {{ ... }}?

Comment: @OliverCooper I've linked the official docs below.  Basically, the default way runs anything between {{}} through htmlspecialchars to prevent XSS attacks.  {!! !!} bypasses this functionality.  So it must be used with care.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade
The section is titled Displaying Unescaped Data

Answer (score 83):

You can use this

```
{!! nl2br(e($text)) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach you can use in Blade files:

```
{!! nl2br(e($onlineSetting->instruction)) !!}
```