# Using Laravel 5, How to detect carriage returns and insert line break

Tags: php, html, laravel, str-replace

I'm following the excellent laravel guide on [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch) and have gotten to the point where we're outputting song titles from a mysql database in video 7.

I wanted to go ahead and add the lyrics which I've done just fine.

Now I'd just like to format it a little better, to add new lines where required.

I've attempted to use str_replace in my view in this manner;

```
<p>{{str_replace("\r","\n", $song->lyrics)}}</p>
```

But nothing appears to happen.  If I use 
 instead of \n, I can see that the carriage return is detected in the correct places, but my output appears like this;

```
looking oh so pretty,<br> I've just got to find my way.<br>
```

Where the < br>'s are just output as normal text.

Can anyone tell me if I'm approaching this in the right way?  I've tried double and triple curly braces and I think I may be forgetting something that mentioned an exclamation mark, but I can't seem to find where it was mentioned again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `{!! nl2br(e($text)) !!}`  it is easier and more effective:
or make your own echo format , both are mentioned here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569955/how-do-i-use-nl2br-in-laravel-5-blade?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Laravel 5 you should use `{!! !!}` to output variable without escaping:

```blade
{!! str_replace("\r","\n", $song->lyrics) !!}
```

Read more: http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0 (Blade Tag Changes section)

Comment: Thanks alot @limonte!  I knew I saw something about exclamation marks somewhere.  I went with this in the end    
    <p>{!! str_replace("\r","<br>", $song->lyrics) !!} </p>
Leads me to another question where I'd like to know why \n doesn't add a new line where <br> does.  It's not important though as I do have something that works for me

Comment: This worked for me `{!! str_replace("\n","<br>", $song->lyrics) !!}` . Thank you