# What is the e() method in laravel views for?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was digging through laravel and I went through how the blade views are interpreted and what I came across was that:

This:

```
{{ $tenant->name }}
```

Translates to this:

```
<?php echo e($tenant->name); ?>
```

I don't understand what the `e()` method is for? I could not find it on the php.net too so I am guessing it is a part of laravel 5 itself. But what does it do?

Comment: If you're here in 2019, please refer to Laravel version 6.x documentation for e() function: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-e

Answer (score 27, accepted):

from the docs:

e()

The e function runs htmlentities over the given string:

```
echo e('<html>foo</html>');

// &lt;html&gt;foo&lt;/html&gt;
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-e

Answer (score 8):

say your going to print some data from the database on a web page, or going to put in to the database as a input like,

```
{{ $tenant->name }}
```

and think value of `$tenant->name` is something like

```
<script>
    alert("Errors....");
</script>
```

after rendering this in the browser you will get an `alert`. This is an security issue so we need to avoid from rendering those content and we don't need these kind of data in out database.

so we need to sanitize those data

to do that laravel provides some options

`HTML::entities($tenant->name);`

and `e()` is and helper function to `HTML::entities`

and you can get the same behavior by using

`e($tenant->name);`

if `$tenant->name` is `<script>alert("Errors....");</script>` then after applying to `e()` you will get something below,

`"&lt;script&gt;
    alert(&quot;Errors....&quot;);
&lt;/script&gt;"`

this is no longer process as a script

here is a good [recipe](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/122/converting-a-html-string-to-entities)

**OR** there is a easy way to do this

use triple curly braces `{{{ }}}` instead of double braces `{{ }}` this will also sanitize the content.