# Using nl2br() in PHP

Tags: php, string, laravel, laravel-blade, nl2br

I am using below code.

```
<?
echo nl2br( 'The situation deteriorated into attacks on New York elite, followed by attacks on black New Yorkers and their property after fierce competition for a decade between 
Irish immigrants and black people for work. Rioters burned the Colored Orphan Asylum to the ground.' , false  ) ;
?>
```

I am getting output like below

```
The situation deteriorated into attacks on New York elite, followed by attacks on black New Yorkers and their property after fierce competition for a decade between <br>
Irish immigrants and black people for work. Rioters burned the Colored Orphan Asylum to the ground.
```

I would like to get output without `<br>` but I need a line break (New Line) at that point.

Comment: nl2br's entire purpose is to add <br>...  And you have a newline break if you are using nl2br.  You can use "\n" to insert a line break inside of quotation marks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blade: escaping text and allowing new lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027236/blade-escaping-text-and-allowing-new-lines)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do this..

```
<?
echo "The situation deteriorated into attacks on New York elite, followed by attacks on black New Yorkers and their property after fierce competition for a decade between\n Irish immigrants and black people for work. Rioters burned the Colored Orphan Asylum to the ground.";
?>
```

Comment: does it work? yes.. answer.. sure.. answer he wants.. not sure.. we'll see what he says..

Comment: and why not? may I see your code? you have 2 choices.. line break (<br>) or new line (\n).. you didnt want the line break.

Comment: Thanks @Rick. I am trying to `echo` the output in a `blade` template file of `Laravel`. Here is the code `<div class="col-xs-12">{{nl2br($story->note)}}</div>`. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry.. I'm just not following.. Do you, or do you not, want that string of text broken into 2 lines?

Comment: I want that string of text broken into 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Btw I do not know what is with the "false" behind the string but if you remove it in your code it works just fine and I see no html break line tag.

```
<?php 
$string = 'The situation deteriorated into attacks on New York elite,followed by attacks on black New Yorkers and their property after fierce competition for a decade between Irish immigrants and black people for work. Rioters burned the Colored Orphan Asylum to the ground.';
function nl2br2($string) { 
$string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $string); 
return $string; 
} 
echo"$string";
?>
```