# How to display new line on blade when generating PDF using DomPDF?

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I want to display the text in separate lines when generate PDF using DomPDF.

I have tried: {{ nl2br($text) }} and {{ nl2br(e($text)) }}, but not working.

```php
{{ $text }}
```

**Current result:**
This is the first line. This is the second line. This is the third line.

**Expected result:**
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the thid line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blade: escaping text and allowing new lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027236/blade-escaping-text-and-allowing-new-lines)

Comment: I think you'll want to use `{!! nl2br(e($text)) !!}` instead

Comment: @morph It works, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

While generating the text for your pdf, after every statement, add `<br>` or `<br/>`.

I think this will fullfill your need.

Answer (score 3):

It works as below:

`{!! nl2br(e($text)) !!}`